# Is in-class enum forward declaration possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, nested, forward-declaration

I know that in C++11 it's possible to forward declare an enum type (if storage type is provided) e.g.

```
enum E : short;
void foo(E e);

....

enum E : short
{
    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_2,
    ....
}
```

But I would like to forward declare an enum defined within a class e.g.

```
enum Foo::E : short;
void foo(E e);

....

class Foo
{
    enum E : short
    {
        VALUE_1,
        VALUE_2,
    ....
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible in C++11 ?

Comment: How about forward declaring the class before enum such `class Foo;`?

Comment: I doubt it. You can't forward declare member functions, typedefs, ect. Why would this be any different? (C++ classes are closed, meaning they can't be edited after defition.) See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836551/forward-declare-a-classs-public-typedef-in-c

Comment: Unlike classes, namespaces can be added to from anywhere. Why not put the enum and the class into a namespace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Forward declaring class scoped enumeration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842006/c-forward-declaring-class-scoped-enumeration), related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238170/forward-declaration-of-nested-enum

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, such a forward declaration isn't possible. [decl.enum]/5 (bold emphasis mine):

> If the *enum-key* is followed by a *nested-name-specifier*, **the
>   *enum-specifier* shall refer to an enumeration that was previously
>   declared directly in the class or namespace to which the
>   *nested-name-specifier* refers** (i.e., neither inherited nor introduced
>   by a using-declaration), and the *enum-specifier* shall appear in a
>   namespace enclosing the previous declaration.

(In this case the *nested-name-specifier* would be the name of your class followed by a `::`.)
You could, though, put the enumeration outside and use an opaque-enum-declaration.

Answer (score 6):

As @Columbo says, you can't declare it in the form you specify.

You can, however, forward declare the nested enum inside the class declaration:

```
class Foo
{
    enum E : short;
};

void foo(Foo::E e);

enum Foo::E : short
{
     VALUE_1,
     VALUE_2,
    ....
};
```

Whether you gain any benefit by doing so depends, of course, on the circumstances.